# Multiple files as command line arguments?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a script to read IP addresses from a file and print the amount in the file. I wasn't fully satisfied so I attempted to modify it to allow reading multiple files, and I would specify the files via cmd arguments. The problem that I'm having is that it seems to read multiple files as one argument.

```
def host_count(*files)

begin

    files.each do
        files = files.join(' ')
        read = IO.read(files)
        reg = read.scan(/(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/).size

        puts "There are " << reg.to_s << " IP addresses in #{files}."
    end

rescue Errno::ENOENT
    puts "File #{files} does not exist!"

rescue TypeError
    puts "Usage: #{$0} [file]"
    puts "Example: #{$0} /home/user/ipfile.txt"
end

end


host_count(ARGV)
```

Running this script with multiple files gives me this error:

> File file1 file2 does not exist!

They aren't separated by commas or anything, so it's not reading my arguments as: ["file1","file2"], which was my original problem. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
files.each do
    files = files.join(' ')
```

Why would you do that?
you're changing the array..
the "files" array is already an array, you don't have to join it with strings.

edit1:
to get the specific file for each run, you should write:

```
files.each do |file|
  puts file # will print "file 1", and in the next iteration will print "file 2".
end
```

Comment: I get this error if I remove that: ./ipcount.rb:13:in `read': can't convert Array into String (TypeError). If I change: read = IO.read(files) to: read = IO.read(files.to_s) then I get this error: ./ipcount.rb:13:in `read': No such file or directory - [["file1", "file2"]] (Errno::ENOENT)
Which is why I originally tried to remove the commas with join.

Comment: you should do `files.each do |file|...` - and then inside the block you'll have the `file` variable, that will be "file1" and then "file 2".